# Symfony2 and nginx web host

Tags: symfony, nginx

Hello i installed symfony2 on my nginx web host but it densest show up the project I've done

http://www.instelamrketing.es its the website and i used this commands to configure the server

http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2013/05/symfony2-under-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-04/

here some error logs

```
tail -f logs/error_log 
#4 /home/intelmarketing.es/public_html/app/cache/prod/classes.php(5519): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(500, 'Uncaught PHP Ex...', Array)
#5 /home/intelmarketing.es/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/ExceptionL in /home/intelmarketing.es/public_html/app/cache/prod/classes.php on line 5141" while reading response header from upstream, client: 180.211.176.176, server: intelmarketing.es, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9007", host: "www.intelmarketing.es"
2013/08/14 18:15:05 [error] 2583#0: *3 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "C:/wamp/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in /home/intelmarketing.es/public_html/app/cache/prod/classes.php:5141
Stack trace:
#0 /home/intelmarketing.es/public_html/app/cache/prod/classes.php(5089): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
#1 /home/intelmarketing.es/public_html/app/cache/prod/classes.php(5018): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
#2 /home/intelmarketing.es/public_html/app/cache/prod/classes.php(5204): Monolog\Handler\AbstractHandler->handleBatch(Array)
#3 /home/intelmarketing.es/public_html/app/cache/prod/classes.php(5419): Monolog\Handler\FingersCrossedHandler->handle(Array)
#4 /home/intelmarketing.es/public_html/app/cache/prod/classes.php(5519): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(500, 'Uncaught PHP Ex...', Array)
#5 /home/intelmarketing.es/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/ExceptionL in /home/intelmarketing.es/public_html/app/cache/prod/classes.php on line 5141" while reading response header from upstream, client: 180.211.176.176, server: intelmarketing.es, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9007", host: "www.intelmarketing.es"
```

what might be the problem?

Thank you
/Aleksandar!

Comment: _'The stream or file "C:/wamp/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: No such file or directory'_ I hesitate to ask, but have you thought that the problem is that there is no such file?

Comment: Yes but i need to change the path from C to my web host which is something like /home/intelmarketing/... etcc

Comment: This error is on the linux production server, after writing it on the development server which is ur local windows machine and uploading it, am i correct?

Comment: if you have SSH access, I would go in and do a `rm -rf app/cache/*`

Comment: Yes mohammed you are correct

Answer (score 1):

Clear your `app/logs` and `app/cache` directories and give your web server permissions to write to them (read [the installation chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html)). You left there some files from your development machine.